# How can use jQuery with an HTML page in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an html page with image. The location of the image and imagename , has been given in the database table. How can I display the image by giving the image path and name  from the database table using jQuery in visual studio code. Anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

So after getting the image src (image location and name) E.g. `example.com/images/image.jpg` you can then use `.Append` or `.HTML` to add the image element with that source.

If you were using AJAX to get the image source, then on the success function you can do

```
var imageSource = data; //data from the ajax call

$('body').append(`<img src="${imageSource}">`);
```

Or if you have the image already on the page, you can edit the source.

```
$("#imageID").attr("src", imageSource);
```

Your question was not very clear so I may have misunderstood your requirements.